# Joining tables on two columns

Tags: mysql, database

How do I join these two tables on ServiceContract and LogicalAdress? When I try LEFT JOIN I end up with way more rows than there initially are.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a8ZiSmfx8iTMe4kwEtfSsb/1

I've tried the query below but it gives me "Query Error: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'ServiceContract' in 'from clause'".

```
SELECT * 
FROM `ServiceErrorsProd`
JOIN `ServiceProductions` USING (ServiceContract, LogicalAdress)
```

Comment: Is your question about the query error (you have SPACES in many of the column names), or the data itself? Fix the typos and [it will work](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a8ZiSmfx8iTMe4kwEtfSsb/1) Note you're joining on columns with different varchar lengths so that in itself may yield unexpected results. Also FYI it's *Address*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error reported by that query is actually:

> Query Error: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'a.LogicalAdress' in 'on clause'

This line:

```
`LogicalAdress ` varchar(53) DEFAULT NULL,
              ^ extra space
```

Should be:

```
`LogicalAdress` varchar(53) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Delimited identifiers allows you to have identifiers with characters normally not allowed, including whitespace.